# DigitalOcean droplet provisioning: Cycle Error

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I want to create multiple droplets while installing some software onto each of them using a remote provisioner. I have the following code:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "server" {
  for_each = var.servers

  name   = each.key
  image  = each.value.image
  size   = each.value.size
  region = each.value.region
  ssh_keys = [
    data.digitalocean_ssh_key.terraform.id
  ]
  tags = each.value.tags

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "mkdir -p  /tmp/scripts/",
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "root"
      private_key = file("${var.ssh_key}")
      host        = digitalocean_droplet.server[each.key].ipv4_address
    }
  }
```

This always results in the following error:

> Error: Cycle: digitalocean_droplet.server["server2"], digitalocean_droplet.server["server1"]

I understand this refers to a circular dependency but how to install the software on each server.

Comment: You have created a cyclic dependency between multiple instances of a resource. You may try with `host = self.ipv4_address`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the issue here is that you are creating a cyclic dependency because you are referring a resource by its name within its own block. To quote [1]:

> References create dependencies, and referring to a resource by name within its own block would create a dependency cycle.

To fix this, you can use a special keyword `self` to reference the same instance that is getting created:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "server" {
  for_each = var.servers

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "mkdir -p  /tmp/scripts/",
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "root"
      private_key = file("${var.ssh_key}")
      host        = self.ipv4_address # <---- here is where you would use the self keyword
    }
  }
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/connection#the-self-object

Comment: Perfect answer Marco, did not know this option. And it works!

Comment: Ha, always happy to help!